# Correct way to disptach from a reducer in createSlice?

Tags: redux-toolkit

What is the correct way to dispacth an action from a reducer in createSlice. e.g. how would I call getX() below :

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const getBusiness = createAsyncThunk('business/getBusiness', () => {
  return axios
    .get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox')
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.status == 200) throw Error(response.statusText);
      return response.data;
    })
    .then((data) => data);
});

export const getX = createAsyncThunk('business/getX', () => {
  return axios
    .get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts')
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.status == 200) throw Error(response.statusText);
      return response.data;
    })
    .then((data) => data);
});

export default createSlice({
  name: 'business',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    data: [],
    test : []
  },
  reducers: {
    // REGULAR REDUCERS
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [getBusiness.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getBusiness.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.error.message;
    },
    [getBusiness.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = action.payload;
      getX() //what is the correct way to dispatch another action??
    },
    [getX.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getX.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.error.message;
    },
    [getX.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.test = action.payload;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just not allowed, ever, to dispatch from a reducer. Reducers have to be side-effect-free, and dispatching is very much a side effect.

In a case like this, you would need to use a middleware.

Either going with the [RTK action listener middleware](https://twitter.com/acemarke/status/1452486196911804420) that's being betaed right now, or just wrapping the original thunk in another thunk.

Something like

```js
const getBusinessAndGetX = () => (dispatch) => {
  try {
    await dispatch(getBusiness()).unwrap()
    dispatch(getX())
  } catch {}
}
```

and then `dispatch(getBusinessAndGetX())`